# Creating tweaks for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vala

I want to create widgets/gadgets and/or customize app themes like Plank themes, WingPanel themes, Files (File Manager) themes, etc for Elementary OS - a Linux distro. But I don't know where to begin. Basically, I want to create "tweaks" and make them available for others to download and use and share.

I know C, C++, C# and Vala (Vala = main programming language used to create software for Elementary OS).

How do we create widgets/gadgets/tweaks for Linux/Ubuntu/Elementary OS? Where do I begin?

Comment: very broad question, but i would suggest to start by reading up on [GTK docs](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.php). can create complex custom widgets with gtk and these are amazingly good tutorials/docs. also gtk has bindings for heaps of languages [including vala]

Comment: @amdixon sorry about the broadness, it's hard to formulate a proper qusetion sometimes when I don't really know exactly what i need. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elementary OS has a developer site](http://elementaryos.org/developer) that you can use to understand their guidelines and touches on some basic topics and APIs. They should also have some links to other docs that go into further detail in certain areas. If you are looking specifically for a GUI application, then I sugggest researching GTK, QT, and Glade as you will be using one of those to help build the interface.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I ended up sticking with Glade and Vala, but I no longer use Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that because it was months old that the question may no longer be relevant to you but there should be an answer for others in case they come across this question.